# Side-loaded records request data that is already loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use side-loading extensively in my Ember Data app to avoid making multiple round-trips to the API, and until now it has always worked out great.

I am using Ember 1.6.0-beta.3, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7, DS.ActiveModelAdapter, and DS.ActiveModelSerializer.

If I save a Foo model, which causes this request:

```
POST /foos

{
  "foo": {
    "name": "Foo"
  }
}
```

The server responds with the created Foo, but also with a side-loaded Bar that references the new Foo.

```
201 Created

{
  "foo": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  "bars": {
    "id": 1,
    "foo_ids": [1]
  }
}
```

After this response, it appears that the Bar does not know that a Foo with ID=1 is in the store, and issues the following request:

```
GET /foos?ids[]=1
```

This request fails because I don't have that endpoint. I would not expect that Ember Data should send this request at all, because we just loaded the Foo with ID=1.

Instead, I would expect that no additional request should be made. Instead, the Bar should become associated with the newly created Foo.

Is my expectation out of line? Is this a bug?

**EDIT**

I was able to work around this issue by explicitly side-loading the foo. This is very inelegant, but hey, it's a work-around.

Specifically, I changed my API to respond with the following after a POST /foos:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  "bars": {
    "id": 1,
    "foo_ids": [1]
  },
  "foos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foo"
  }]
}
```

Then the side-loaded Bar doesn't try to load it's Foo.

I'm going to leave this open, because a work-around is not a fix.

Comment: I confirm this issue ( example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/numez/1/edit). I think, it is a bug. If I find some time, I will try to create a failing test and report it at github

Comment: It has been reported https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1925